# How to get image down arrow to scroll down to end of page after 2nd click. First click is fine

Tags: jquery, html

I set up the image icon and using the javascript and jquery. The image down arrow works as expected, (first click takes me to second row grid box (downward), now needing the second click to take me to bottom of page, but I tried implementing another set of js code but its not working, even tried duplicate image with diff class and still not working.

I tried replicating the js code and the image code, but neither work. I have the arrow image set to fixed position. Also curious as to how the same image can utilize the same code if it has one class on it already.

```
$(function() {
    $('.scroll-down').click (function() {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('section.buckets').offset().top }, 'slow');
      return false;
    });

    /* $('section.buckets').click (function() {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('section.more').offset().top }, 'slow');
        return false;
    });  this is the second code is tried to implement doesnt work*/
}); 

<!--Here is the img tied to down arrow icon-->
<a href="#" class="scroll-down" address="true"><i class="fa fa-angle-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

<!--CSS-->
.down {
position: fixed;
top: 93%;
left: 97%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
width: 60px;
height: 60px;
border-radius: 50%;
font-size:48px;
border: 2px solid #00567d;
background: #04a9f5;
box-shadow: 0 0 0 5px #fff; 0 5px 25px rgba(0,0,0,.8);
overflow: hidden;
}

.down:before {
content: '';
position: absolute;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
background: rgba(0,0,0,.1);

}

.down .fa {
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
color: #fff;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
animation: animate 3s linear infinite;
text-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.2);

}

@keyframes animate {
0% {
    top: -10%;
} 
40% {
    top: 60%;
} 
60% {
    top: 30%;
} 
80% {
    top: 60%;
} 
100% {
    top: 110%;
} 
}

/* Buckets section */

.buckets {
padding: 2em 1em 1em;
background: #3E454C;

}

.buckets ul {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.buckets li {
margin-bottom: 1em;
background: white;
list-style-type: none;
}

.bucket {
padding: 1.5em;
}

/* More section */

.more {
padding: 2em;
}

/*--------------------------------------------------------------
Use flex to create a three-bucket layout
--------------------------------------------------------------*/

@media screen and (min-width: 700px) {
@supports (display: flex) {

    .buckets ul {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-around;
        align-items: stretch;

    }

    .buckets li {
        width: 31%;
    }

}
}

<!--HTML-->
<section class="buckets">
<ul>
  <li>
    <img src="./images/image1.png" alt="">
      <div class="bucket">
    <h3 class="bucket-title">headline1</h3>
    <p>paragraph1</p>
    </div><!-- .bucket -->                        </li>
  <li>
    <img src="./images/image2.png" alt="">
    <div class="bucket">                
        <h3 class="bucket-title">headline2</h3>
    <p>paragraph2</p>                               
    </div><!-- .bucket -->                                      
  </li>
  <li>
   <img src="./images/image3.png" alt="">
   <div class="bucket">
    <h3 class="bucket-title">headline3</h3>
            <p>paragraph3</p>                   
   </div><!-- .bucket -->           
  </li>
  </ul>                         
</section><!-- .buckets -->     

<section class="more">
   <div class="more-content">
     <h4 class="content-title">moretitle</h4>
     <button><a href="page.html">Learn More</a></button>
 </div><!-- .more-content -->
</section><!-- .more -->
```

When I click the down arrow icon now it works as expected, takes me downward to second row grid box, but I don't know how to implement the code for the 2nd click to take me to bottom of page, then the 3rd click to take me back up with an up arrow instead of a down arrow.

Comment: Can you provide the HTML and CSS too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(function() {


    function determineScrollTarget()
    {
      var currentPos = $(window).scrollTop();
      
      //Add whatever stops you want to scroll to here.
      //Be sure to always order them from the top of the page to the bottom.
      var positions = [
        $('.content1').offset().top,
        $('.content2').offset().top,
        //Add new elements here.
        $(document).height() - $(window).height(), //Bottom of page
      ];
      
      
      var targetScrollPosition = 0;
      //Find the first position on the list that is lower than the current scroll position.
      for (var i = 0; i < positions.length; i++)
      {
        if (positions[i] > currentPos) 
        {
          targetScrollPosition = positions[i];
          break;
        }
       
      }
      
      return targetScrollPosition;
    }

    $('.arrow').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: determineScrollTarget() }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

```css
.page
{
height: 1000px;
}


.content1
{
background: red;
margin-top:10em;
height: 10em;
margin-bottom: 70em;
}

.content2
{
background: blue;
margin-top:50em;
height: 10em;
margin-bottom: 10em;
}

.content3
{
background: teal;
margin-top:50em;
height: 10em;
margin-bottom: 10em;
}

.arrow
{
  position: fixed;
  right: 30px;
  top: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: #EEE;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;
 
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="page">

<a class="arrow">Press Me \/</a>

<div class="content1">
<h1>Content 1</h1>
</div>

<div class="content2">
<h1>Content 2</h1>
</div>

<div class="content3">
<h1>Content 3</h1>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```